# Text wrap in row widgets

Tags: dart, flutter

I have nested rows using this code:

```
    Row(
    mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
    children: <Widget>[
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record),
          Text(
            'the text in the first row',
          ),
        ],
      ),
      Row(
        children: <Widget>[
          Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record),
          Text(
            'the text in the second row',
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  )
```

When there is space, I want the rows to be side by side (current behavior):

[image]

Currently, when it overflows, the text gets cut off like this:

[image: nested rows]

Is there a way to force the second row onto a new line when there's no space, so it looks like this?

[image: new lines]

Comment: Instead of first row use wrap widget. So wrap widget will have the children rows

Comment: @anmol.majhail i think you mean both as wraps

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something on these lines will work:

```
Wrap(
      direction: Axis.horizontal,
      children: <Widget>[
        Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record),
            Text(
              'the text ',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record),
            Text(
              'more the text in the first row',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record),
            Text(
              'the text in the second row',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record),
            Text(
              'more text in the second row',
            ),
          ],
        ),
        Wrap(
          children: <Widget>[
            Icon(Icons.fiber_manual_record),
            Text(
              'the text in the third row',
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Answer (score 10):

Try this! It worked for me.

```
new Flexible(child: new Text('Auto wrap'))
```

Answer (score 3):

```
            Row(
          children: [
            Checkbox(
              onChanged: (bool value) {},
              value: true,
            ),
            Flexible(
              child: RichText(
                strutStyle: StrutStyle(height: 1.4),
                softWrap: true,
                text: TextSpan(style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12, color: ColorUtil.hexToColor("#999999")), children: <InlineSpan>[
                  TextSpan(text: "ฉันได้อ่านและยอมรับ "),
                  TextSpan(text: "ฉันได้อ่านและยอมรับ "),
                  TextSpan(
                      text: "สัญญาการให้บริการ & ข้อตกลงความเป็นส่วนตัว",
                      style: TextStyle(color: ColorUtil.hexToColor("#666666")),
                      recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                        ..onTap = () {
                          Navigator.pushNamed(context, "/profile/terms_policy");
                        }),
                ]),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
```

this work for me. Wrap with Flexible

Answer (score 2):

If you wrapped `Text` widget with `Padding` adding `Flexible` around `Padding` do the trick.

```
          Row(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Icon(
                  Icons.check,
                  color: Colors.green,
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 16,
                ),
                Flexible(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0, 8, 0, 0),
                    child: Text(
                      'Some text',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          fontSize: 18, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
```